# Get all IP's associated or used by process

Tags: linux, networking, openvpn

I would like to retrieve all IP addresses associated with a specific Linux process.

e.g I have OpenVPN running (or some webserver,etc.).

using `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep openvpn` will give me this result:

```
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123             0.0.0.0:*                           1389/openvpn    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1194            0.0.0.0:*                           7755/openvpn
```

I have tried ss but that does not yield any IP's.

note: OS - Ubuntu 14.04

**UPDATE**

```
sudo lsof -i | grep ntp
openvpn    1389              nobody    4u  IPv4 3995641409      0t0  UDP *:ntp 

sudo lsof -i | grep openvpn
openvpn    1389              nobody    4u  IPv4 3995641409      0t0  UDP *:ntp 
openvpn    7755              nobody    5u  IPv4  516224428      0t0  UDP *:openvpn
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try with `-a` option: `sudo netstat -tulpna`. Worked on Centos.

Comment: Because UDP is "stateless", you'll have to sniff traffic.

Answer (score 3):

try `lsof -i` or variations of that.  `lsof` can also show open files/devices.

```
COMMAND    PID    USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
chromium- 1338 username  197u  IPv4  26478      0t0  TCP 172.20.20.20:35906->stackoverflow.com:https (ESTABLISHED)
chromium- 1338 username  198u  IPv4  26227      0t0  TCP 172.20.20.20:58512->ec2-54-235-77-158.compute-1.amazonaws.com:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
chromium- 1338 username  203u  IPv4  26294      0t0  TCP 172.20.20.20:35864->stackoverflow.com:https (ESTABLISHED)
chromium- 1338 username  213u  IPv4  20381      0t0  TCP 172.20.20.20:52572->qj-in-f138.1e100.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
```

**NOTE:** your `lsof` output shows that your daemon is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0).